# Firebase Realtime Database, synchronized with Google sheet, accepts wrong Date from Datepicker sheet cell

Tags: firebase, api, flutter, google-sheets

**How Google Sheet looks**

[image]

**How Firebase Database looks**

[image]

So the date keeps saving as the day before date;

**At Google script appsscript.json is set my real timezone**:

```
"timeZone": "Europe/Kiev"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The date/time values in the database are stored in `Z` timezone, so it indeed seems like a timezone offset may be causing this. It's impossible to say where that happens though without seeing the code that stores the values from the sheet in the database.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I used a standard code from this github repo https://gist.github.com/edwinlee/85ac9033a133d056a8ded6b74f27f30f#file-code-gs

Comment: Check that the _spreadsheet's_ timezone is set correctly at **File > Spreadsheet settings**.

Comment: @doubleunary The spreadsheet's timezone is set to Kiev (GTM + 2). The date field in firebase is always the day before, despite the time during the day, so for now I believe the issue isn't related to timezone messing .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the two timestamp values actually refer to the same moment in time. Firebase timestamps are [always in UTC](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp).

`2021-05-16 00:00 GMT+3` refers to the same point in time as `2021-05-15 21:00 GMT+0`. The timezone difference between Kiev and GMT is two hours + one hour because of daylight saving time, so during `EEST` the two serialized values will *look like* they are three hours apart.

You can deal with the timezone difference in the client, displaying the timestamp value you retrieve from Firebase in the local time of the client. If the client is in the Kiev timezone, the value will then look the same as it was in the Google Sheet originally.

If you want to save the date as a static text string instead of as a `Date` object, you may want to convert it in Apps Script with `const timezone = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone()` and `const dateString = Utilities.formatDate(myDate, timezone, "yyyy-MM-dd")`, or in JavaScript with the [Intl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) object or a library like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

Comment: You are right - the time was always set as 21:00 in firebase, so + 3hours was making the issue with stored date. I set  spreadsheet's timezone to GMT+00:00 and the issue has gone. Thanks.